# camel AdviceWithRouteBuilder deprecation

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using camel 2.15.1 and I'm trying to use adviceWith() but I keep getting deprecation warnings. Below is the relevant snippet:

```
routeDefinition.adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:doSomething")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
        }
    });
```

I know I can avoid the deprecation warnings by casting camelContext to ModelCamelContext but casting like that has a bit of a smell to it. Is casting the right way to handle it?

https://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those deprecatations has been removed in future release as we really just want people to access all what they need from `CamelContext`.

But it has an adapt method so you can adapt to the type without type casting

```
ModelCamelContext mcc = context.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
```

Comment: So im not sure how this replaces using adviceWith, how do you tweak endpoints in the route using this approach vs. how it is done via adviceWith?

Comment: the `adapt` method is not present in Camel 2.13.0, should I rely on the deprecated methods then?

Comment: You can just type cast the CamelContext

Answer (score 3):

This solved the problem for my unit tests:

```
public void testMe() throws Exception{
    CamelContext context = this.context();

    // Get the route that we're after by ID.
    RouteDefinition route = context.getRouteDefinition("<routeID>");

    //override the default send endpoint.
    route.adviceWith(context.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class), new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:overrideme")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .to("mock:inbound");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for camel version change 2 to 3, here what you can go for regarding the RouteDefination and AdviceWith , ModelCamelContext, CamelContext

```
 `private void methodName() throws Exception {
            AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, "routeId" , route -> {

                    route.interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:doSomething").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint();

                    
            });
   context.start();
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `adviceWith` method was moved as explained [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_7.html#_advicewith).

Answer (score 0):

AdviceWithRouteBuilder was also used in [this example](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/9921df2acbe6e3c1d825f4455668097db0205841/chapter9/advicewith/src/test/java/camelinaction/AdviceWithMockEndpointsTest.java), which I believe is an example of this question. For now, in 2022 I think it could be better represented in the following:

```java
package TestExamples.AdviceExamples;

import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit5.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

/**
 * Unit test demonstrating various functionality of using advice-with
 */
public class AdviceWithMockEndpointsTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject("mock:seda:camel")
    protected MockEndpoint camelPoint;

    @EndpointInject("mock:seda:other")
    protected MockEndpoint otherPoint;
    



    @Test
    public void testMockEndpoints() throws Exception {

        // must start Camel after we are done using advice-with
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, "quotes", routeBuilder ->{
            routeBuilder.weaveByToUri("seda:camel").replace().to(camelPoint);
            routeBuilder.weaveByToUri("seda:other").replace().to(otherPoint);


        });
        context.start();

        camelPoint.expectedBodiesReceived("Camel rocks");
        otherPoint.expectedBodiesReceived("Bad donkey");

        template.sendBody("seda:quotes", "Camel rocks");
        template.sendBody("seda:quotes", "Bad donkey");

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("seda:quotes").routeId("quotes")
                        .choice()
                        .when(simple("${body} contains 'Camel'"))
                        .to("seda:camel")
                        .otherwise()
                        .to("seda:other");
            }
        };
    }
}
```